# bibtex Confusion?

Tags: bibtex

I have the following:

```
@Book{Faber,
ALTauthor = {•},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Fluid Dynamics for Physicists},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
year = {1995},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTaddress = {•},
OPTedition = {1},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}

@Book{Goff,
  ALTauthor = {•},
  ALTeditor = {•},
  title = {Gold Medal Physics: The Science of Sport},
  publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
  year = {2010},
  OPTkey = {•},
  OPTvolume = {•},
  OPTnumber = {•},
  OPTseries = {•},
  OPTaddress = {•},
  OPTedition = {•},
  OPTmonth = {•},
  OPTnote = {•},
  OPTannote = {•}
  }
```

This is all saved as mybib.bib.  Then I use

```
  \bibliography{mybib.bib}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Then there is no bibliography :(

Comment: @someonr -- Well, you need to run `latex` before *and* after running `bibtex`.  The normal sequence is `latex file.tex`, `bibtex file.aux`, `latex file.tex`, `latex file.tex`.  It is not clear what yankeefan11 is or is not doing, however.

Comment: @jon yes you are right. I removed my confusing comment.

Comment: With no feedback, I think the most likely situation here is that in the question I've duped to.

Answer (score 0):

Well I reckon you can delete all those entries which have not been filled (just to avoid confusion).

To get bibliography rendered, first of all run the bib file using bibtex. Then, you can build your document in latex which will render the bibliography in your output. Hope that works.

Comment: As is, this is inaccurate.  You *must* run some form of `latex` first (whether `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`): otherwise, there will be no information for `bibtex` to pick up.